# Finding the total number of set-bits from 1 to n

Tags: algorithm

Write an algorithm to find `F(n)` the number of bits set to 1, in all numbers from 1 to n for any given value of n.

Complexity should be `O(log n)`

For example:

```
1: 001
2: 010
3: 011
4: 100
5: 101
6: 110
```

So

```
F(1) = 1,  
F(2) = F(1) + 1 = 2,
F(3) = F(2) + 2 = 4,
F(4) = F(3) + 1 = 5,
etc.
```

I can only design an `O(n)` algorithm.

Comment: Hint: If you can design an O(1) solution for "how many numbers have a particular bit set from 1 to N", you can design an O(log N) solution for total number of bits.

Comment: umm, I have a question. Are you asking "How to find the total bits set in a number?" or something else?

Comment: @owlstead I don't know about you, but when I find a question that's interesting to me I invest time in answering it regardless of how much time somebody else already has, especially for classic puzzlers like interview questions. I don't get the big deal about investing time before posting - you either appreciate interview questions or you don't. It's not like somebody is asking you to do their job for them... sheesh..

Comment: @noMAD, for example, given n = 3, since 1 = 01, 2 = 10, 3 = 11, the total number of 1 bit from 1 to 3 is 1+1+2=4. Hope this clarity.

Comment: @gigantt.com I was just commenting on the formatting of the question, hoping to get the asker to create a question that doesn't need translation, I'll edit the "ur"'s out myself, maybe the asker learned English from YouTube... oh, too late.

Comment: Adding to Jimmy's hint: maybe it's easier to think in columns rather than in rows.

Comment: @OmriBarel: is it have to do with `[010101 in units place]` `[00110011 in one's place]` etc..?? I think so..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number of 1s in the two's complement binary representations of integers in a range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942732/number-of-1s-in-the-twos-complement-binary-representations-of-integers-in-a-ran)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The way to solve these sorts of problems is to write out the first few values, and look for a pattern

```
Number  binary   # bits set   F(n)
1       0001     1            1
2       0010     1            2
3       0011     2            4
4       0100     1            5
5       0101     2            7
6       0110     2            9
7       0111     3            12
8       1000     1            13
9       1001     2            15
10      1010     2            17
11      1011     3            20
12      1100     2            22
13      1101     3            25
14      1110     3            28
15      1111     4            32
```

It takes a bit of staring at, but with some thought you notice that the binary-representations of the first 8 and the last 8 numbers are exactly the same, except the first 8 have a `0` in the MSB *(most significant bit)*, while the last 8 have a `1`.  Thus, for example to calculate `F(12)`, we can just take `F(7)` and add to it the number of set bits in 8, 9, 10, 11 and 12.  But that's the same as the number of set-bits in 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 *(ie. `F(4)`)*, plus one more for each number!

```
#    binary
0    0 000
1    0 001
2    0 010
3    0 011
4    0 100
5    0 101
6    0 110
7    0 111

8    1 000  <--Notice that rightmost-bits repeat themselves
9    1 001     except now we have an extra '1' in every number!
10   1 010
11   1 011
12   1 100
```

Thus, for `8 <= n <= 15`, `F(n) = F(7) + F(n-8) + (n-7)`.  Similarly, we could note that for `4 <= n <= 7`, `F(n) = F(3) + F(n-4) + (n-3)`; and for `2 <= n <= 3`, `F(n) = F(1) + F(n-2) + (n-1)`.  In general, if we set `a = 2^(floor(log(n)))`, then `F(n) = F(a-1) + F(n-a) + (n-a+1)`

---

This doesn't quite give us an `O(log n)` algorithm; however, doing so is easy.  If `a = 2^x`, then note in the table above that for `a-1`, the first bit is set exactly `a/2` times, the second bit is set exactly `a/2` times, the third bit... all the way to the x'th bit.  Thus, `F(a-1) = x*a/2 = x*2^(x-1)`.  In the above equation, this gives us

```
F(n) = x*2x-1 + F(n-2x) + (n-2x+1)
```

Where `x = floor(log(n))`.  Each iteration of calculating `F` will essentially remove the MSB; thus, this is an `O(log(n))` algorithm.

Comment: I find it crazy that so many people believe this algorithm is lg n. It's not. If you can't read it, try implementing it.

Comment: "Each iteration of calculating F will essentially remove the MSB; thus, this is an O(log(n)) algorithm." That's not a true statement. You don't get x for free, do you? so you  for each looping F(n-2^x) you must get x, then x*2^(x-1), etc.

Comment: @kasavbre, tribal: Care to explain?  It is indeed `O(log n)` if you assume `2^x` is an `O(1)` operation *(which is it on real-world computers, using left-shift)*

Comment: @tribal: Yes, obtaining `x` can be done theoretically be done in `O(1)` in hardware.  In fact, on modern x86 and x64 machines, it is:  It's called the [BSR instruction](http://www.fermi.mn.it/linux/quarta/x86/bsr.htm) *([__builtin_clz](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.4/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) in GCC; [_BitScanReverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbxyd7zd%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) in VC++)*.  In either case, though, I really don't believe this bit of pedantry deserves a downvote :|

Comment: So you see the problem? Not all machines provide BSF/BSR. Otherwise, both algo (you and @kasavbere) are exactly the same -- except s/he actually provides implementation. You two should kiss and make up! I'll give both of you the upvote.

Comment: unless the interviewer had BSF/BSR in mind, both you and @kasavbere got it wrong. :)

Answer (score 8):

consider the below:

```
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
1000
1001
1010
1011
1100
1101
1110
1111
```

If you want to find total number of set bits from 1 to say 14 (1110)
Few Observations:

1. `0th` bit (LSB) `1` bit appears once every two bit (see vertically) so number of set bits = `n/2 +`(`1` if `n's 0th bit is 1` else `0`)
2. 1st bit : 2 consecutive 1s appear every four bits (see 1st bit vertically along all numbers)
   number of set bits in `1st` bit position = `(n/4 *2) + 1` (since `1st` bit is a set, else `0`)
3. `2nd` bit: `4` consecutive `1s` appear every `8` bits ( this one is a bit tricky)
   number of set bits in 2nd position = `(n/8*4 )+ 1`( since `2nd` bit is set, else `0`) `+ ((n%8)%(8/2))`
   The last term is to include the number of `1s` that were outside first `(n/8)` group of bits (`14/8 =1` considers only `1` group ie. `4` set bits in `8` bits. we need to include `1s` found in last `14-8 = 6` bits)
4. `3rd` bit: `8` consecutive 1s appear every `16` bits (similar to above)
   number of set bits in `3rd` position = `(n/16*8)+1`(since `3rd` bit is set, else `0`)`+ ((n%16)%(16/2))`

so we do `O(1)` calculation for each bit of a number `n`.
a number contains `log2(n)` bits. so when we iterate the above for all positions of `n` and add all the set bits at each step, we get the answer in `O(logn)` steps

Answer (score 7):

If `n= 2^k-1, then F(n)=k*(n+1)/2`

For a general `n`, let `m` be the largest number such that `m = 2^k-1` and `m<=n`. `F(n) = F(m) + F(n-m-1) + (n-m)`.

Corner condition: `F(0)=0` and `F(-1)=0`.

Answer (score 4):

A quick search for the values of the sequence F lead to this integer sequence
http://oeis.org/A000788

There I spotted a formula:
a(0) = 0, a(2n) = a(n)+a(n-1)+n, a(2n+1) = 2a(n)+n+1         (a is the same as F since I just copy the formula from oeis)

which could be used to compute a(n) in log(n).

Here's my sample C++ code:

```
memset(cache, -1, sizeof(cache))
cache[0] = 0

int f(int n)
    if cache[n] != -1 return cache[n];
    cache[n] = n % 2 ? (2 * f(n / 2) + n / 2 + 1) : (f(n / 2) + f(n / 2 - 1) + n / 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

This question can be solved using DP with Bitmasking.

The basic intuition behind bottom-up approach is that we are going to directly access number of set bits in the number having value current_number/2 and we are also going to check whether last bit is set in this current_number or not by just doing and operation with 1.

current_number/2 or current_number>>1 basically removes the last bit of this current_number so to include that bit in our count we have to manually check the last bit of this number using & operation.

This would be expression for computing number of set bits in a number i
dp[i]=dp[i>>1]+(i&1)

If you still get stuck while solving this question then you can refer to the following video for a better explanation:-

Video Link:
https://youtu.be/fCvfud4p6No

Answer (score 2):

Let `k` be the number of bits needed for `n`.

for `0,...,2^(k-1)-1` each bit is up exactly for half of the numbers, so we have `(k-1)*2^(k-1)/2 =  (k-1)*2^(k-2)` bits up so far. We only need to check what's up with the numbers that are bigger then `2^(k-1)-1`

We also have for those `n-2^(k-1)-1` bits "up" for the MSB.

So we can derive to the recursive function:

```
f(n) = (k-1)*2^(k-2) + n-(2^(k-1)-1) + f(n-(2^(k-1)))
           ^               ^            ^
         first            MSBs        recursive call for 
       2^(k-1)-1                      n-2^(k-1) highest numbers
        numbers
```

Where base is `f(0) = 0` and `f(2^k) = k*2^(k-1) + 1` [as we seen before, we know exactly how much bits are up for `2^(k-1)-1`, and we just need to add 1 - for the MSB of `2^k`]

Since the value sent to `f` is reduced by by at least half at every iteration, we get total of `O(logn)`

Comment: "each bit is up exactly for half of the numbers, so we have `2^k/2` bits up" - it's `k*2^k/2`, each number is k bits long. also the resursive formula is not right, see the definition of f(x).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: fixed, thanks.. I followed the logic trail without putting to much thaught into details, thanks for catching that up!

Comment: no problem ;) though you start wondering what kind of drugs the upvoters are using.. :D

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: I editted again, it is actually `(k-1) * 2^k/2` since we are talking only about the first k-1 bits... I think the upvoters are after an approach and not necesserally a perfect solution...

Comment: in that case it's `(k-1) * 2^(k-1)/2`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: doh. of course it is. I think it is pretty set now. thanks for helping!

Comment: -1 this answer is *still* not correct, you are still missing a term.  See my or ElKamina's answer for the missing term.

Comment: This new edit including the missing term is *still* not correct - try for example `F(4)`.  You get `4`, instead of the correct answer `5`

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: Thank you, I extended the base, I tried to show my logic and unrightfully neglected the details. Anyway, the main idea of my answer was to provide the logic how this question should be addressed - and it did its purpose, concidering following answers.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution to this. Time complexity : O (Log n)

```
public int countSetBits(int n){
    int count=0;
    while(n>0){
        int i= (int)(Math.log10(n)/Math.log10(2));
        count+= Math.pow(2, i-1)*i;
        count+= n-Math.pow(2, i)+1;
        n-= Math.pow(2, i);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some clarification with comments which will be useful

Answer (score 1):

short and sweet!

```
 public static int countbits(int num){
    int count=0, n;
    while(num > 0){
        n=0;
        while(num >= 1<<(n+1))
            n++;
        num -= 1<<n;
        count += (num + 1 + (1<<(n-1))*n);
    }
    return count;
}//countbis
```

Comment: @kasavbere, can you explain it? Thanks.

Comment: FihopZz is there a reason you marked @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft as the correct answer instead of this one?

Comment: Well for one thing this is `O((log n)^2)`, not `O(log n)`

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft, You don't honestly believe an implementation of your algorithm would be faster than mine, do you? If you do, show it.

Comment: This looks as good as it gets. I think it's the correct answer. Upvote! @Nemo, what were you talking about?

Comment: @tribal Original version was n log n...  I removed my down vote on this version.  By the way, this whole question is a duplicate

Comment: I see. I also checked @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft algo. It's not O(log n).

Comment: This is the same as @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft algo. Good job for a great implementation. BSF/BSR may be an option for getting n.

Comment: I see; they seem the same. My algorithm is not  O((log n)^2) by the way. There is a lower O bound even without BSF/BSR: And that's due to the probabilistic distribution of the set bits. e.g. for each num===2^n, the loop is entered only once.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the java function

```
private static int[] findx(int i) {
    //find the biggest power of two number that is smaller than i
    int c = 0;
    int pow2 = 1;
    while((pow2<< 1) <= i) {
        c++;
        pow2 = pow2 << 1;
    }
    return new int[] {c, pow2};
}

public static int TotalBits2(int number) {
    if(number == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    int[] xAndPow = findx(number);
    int x = xAndPow[0];
    return x*(xAndPow[1] >> 1) + TotalBits2(number - xAndPow[1]) + number - xAndPow[1] + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is coded in java...
logic: say number is 34, binary equal-ant is 10010, which can be written as 10000 + 10. 
10000 has 4 zeros, so count of all 1's before this number is 2^4(reason below). so count is 2^4 + 2^1 + 1(number it self). so answer is 35.
*for binary number 10000. total combinations of filling 4 places is 2*2*2*2x2(one or zero). So total combinations of ones is 2*2*2*2.

```
public static int getOnesCount(int number) {
    String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(number);
    return getOnesCount(binary);
}

private static int getOnesCount(String binary) {
    int i = binary.length();

    if (i>0 && binary.charAt(0) == '1') {
        return gePowerof2(i) + getOnesCount(binary.substring(1));
    }else if(i==0)
        return 1;
    else
        return getOnesCount(binary.substring(1));

}
//can be replaced with any default power function
private static int gePowerof2(int i){
    int count = 1;
    while(i>1){
        count*=2;
        i--;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, this question can also be done by the method of lookup table. Precompute the number of set bits from 0-255 and store it. Post that, we can calculate the number of set bits in any number by breaking a given number into two parts of 8 bits each. For each part, we can lookup in the count array formed in the first step.  For example, if there is a 16 bit number like,

`x = 1100110001011100`, here, the number of set bits = number of set bits in the first byte + number of set bits in the second byte. Therefore, for obtaining, first byte,

`y = (x & 0xff)`
`z = (x >> 8) & (0xff)`
`total set bits = count[y] + count[z]`

This method will run in O(n) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its late to reply, but here are my findings.

Tried solving the problem with following approach, for number N every bitno ( from LSB to MSB, say LSB starts with bitno 1 and incrementing with next bit value) number of bits set can be calculated as , (N/(2 topower bitno) * (2 topower bitno-1) + { (N%(2 topower bitno)) - [(2 topower bitno-1) - 1] }

Have written recursive function for it C/C++ please check. I am not sure but I think its complexity is log(N). Pass function 2 parameters, the number (no) for which we want bits to be calculated and second start count from LSB , value 1.

```
int recursiveBitsCal(int no, int bitno){
int res = int(no/pow(2,bitno))*int(pow(2,bitno-1));
int rem1 = int(pow(2,bitno-1)) -1;
int rem = no % int(pow(2,bitno));
if (rem1 < rem) res += rem -rem1;
if ( res <= 0 )
    return 0;
else
    return res + recursiveBitsCal(no, bitno+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(int(input())):
    n=int(input())
    c=0
    m=13

    if n==0:
        print(c)
    while n%8!=0 or n!=0:
        t=bin(n)[2:]
        c+=t.count('1')
        n=n-1
    if n!=0:
        j=n//8
        if j==1:
            c+=m
        else:
            c+=m+((j-1)*7)
    print(c)
```

Comment: simple in math logic.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow aka. "SO"
Glad to have you apart of the community!
Could you explain your answer and why it is better or different from the rest?
Also, Please be sure to checkout our help section
https://stackoverflow.com/help/
and
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
as this will guide you in getting more support from us in the community.

Comment: just use pen and paper and see the pattern of every 8 consecutive integers...then see my code to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

```
int countSetBits(int n)
{
    n++;
    int powerOf2 = 2;
    int setBitsCount = n/2;
    while (powerOf2 <= n)
    {
        int numbersOfPairsOfZerosAndOnes = n/powerOf2;
        setBitsCount += (numbersOfPairsOfZerosAndOnes/2) * powerOf2;
        setBitsCount += (numbersOfPairsOfZerosAndOnes&1) ? (n%powerOf2) : 0;
        powerOf2 <<= 1;
    }
    return setBitsCount;
}
```

Please check my article on geeksforgeeks.org for detailed explanation.
Below is the link of the article
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-total-set-bits-in-all-numbers-from-1-to-n-set-2/

Comment: Consider adding explanation on SO instead of posting only link.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post came in late to the party, please find `logn` solution below:

```
static int countSetBitWithinRange(int n)
{
    int x = n + 1, index = 0, count = 0;
    int numberOfOnesInAGroup = (int)Math.pow(2, index);
    while(x >= numberOfOnesInAGroup)
    {
        int countOfZeroOnePairs = (x / numberOfOnesInAGroup);
        int numberOfPairsOfZerosAndOnes = countOfZeroOnePairs / 2;
        int numberOfSetBits = numberOfPairsOfZerosAndOnes * numberOfOnesInAGroup;
        //If countOfZeroOnePairs is even then the pairs are complete else there will be ones that do not have a corresponding zeros pair
        int remainder = (countOfZeroOnePairs % 2 == 1) ? (x % numberOfOnesInAGroup) : 0;
        count = count + numberOfSetBits + remainder;
        numberOfOnesInAGroup = 1 << ++index;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = int(input("Any number:\n"))
y = (bin(x))
print(y)
v = len(y) -2
print(v)
```

Comment: Thanks for your first answer. Answers are helpful when you provide an explanation for your code so others can understand what is happening. Please also take a look https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting for info on formatting your code.

Answer (score 0):

The O(Log(N)) solution is based on the repetition in python is as follows. its based on the simple contribution technique.

```
def solve(A):
    check_array = 1
    output = 1
    final_sum = 0
    offset = 0
    while(A>0):
        check_array <<=1
        if check_array > A:
            check_array>>=1
            A -=check_array
            output = output + check_array * offset
            final_sum += output
            check_array = 1
            output =1
            offset +=1
        add = output+ check_array//2 -1
        output += add
    return final_sum
```

solve(8) = 13