# Given a number n, find out how many numbers have digit 2 in the range 0...n

Tags: algorithm

It's an interview question.

> Given a number n, find out how many numbers have digit 2 in the range 0...n

For example ,

> input = 13  output  = 2  (2 and 12)

I gave the usual O(n^2) solution but is there a better approach.

is there any 'trick' formula that will help me to get the answer right away

Comment: O(n²)? If you mean, generate the numbers and check the digits, that's O(n lg n), since each number n is represented by O(lg n) digits.

Comment: It's a permuttation question..

Comment: @FredFoo each number is represented by log10(n) digits, so it's O(nlog10(n)) (number of digits in a base 10 number is log10(n))

Answer (score 27):

Count the numbers that do **not** have the digit 2. Among the  numbers less than 10<sup>k</sup>, there are exactly 9<sup>k</sup> of them. Then it remains to treat the numbers from 10<sup>k</sup> to `n`, where

```
10^k <= n < 10^(k+1)
```

which you can do by treating the first digits individually (the cases 2 and others have to be differentiated), and then the first 2 digits etc.

For example, for `n = 2345`, we find there are `9^3 = 729` numbers without the digit 2 below 1000. There are again 729 such numbers in the range from 1000 to 1999. Then in the range from 2000 to 2345, there are none, for a total of 1458, hence the numbers containing the digit 2 are

```
2345 - 1458 = 887
```

Comment: Could you explain how you got 9^k numbers, I'm not very good with combinatorics.

Comment: If you write numbers with leading zeros, the numbers 0 to `10^k - 1` are precisely the numbers you can write with exactly `k` digits. For each of the digits, there are 9 (`== 10 - 1`) possible choices (`0,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`). The choices are independent, so the total number of choices is the product of the number of choices for each digit, `9*9*...*9 = 9^k`. If you were after the numbers containing neither a digit 2 nor a digit 5, it would be `8^k` (8 = 10 - 2). The same principle holds for representations of numbers in other bases. However, since numbers don't really have leading zeros, cont...

Comment: ..., forbidding the digit 0 is slightly different. Then you can't add leading zeros to get all numbers to the same length, and the count of numbers below `10^k` that don't have a digit 0 is `9^1 + 9^2 + 9^3 + ... + 9^k = 9 * (9^k - 1)/8`. If you forbid 0 and `d` other digits, leaving `e = 9-d` eligible digits, you get `e^1 + e^2 + ... + e^k = e * (e^k - 1)/(e-1)`. (Replace 9 by `base-1` for bases other than 10.)

Answer (score 2):

argument 'digit' is the one which we want to count and arg 'number' is till where we want to count. For eg: If we want to count occurrences of '1', from 0 to 12, call the function with digit=1, and number=12, and it will return the number of occurrences of '1'.

```cpp
int countOccurrences(int digit, int number)
{
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i=1; i<number; i++)
    {
        int j = i;
        while(j > 0)
        {
            if(j%10 == digit)
                counter++;
            j /= 10;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried executing this method? It returns 12, on countOccurrences(1,20), not 3.

Comment: This counts the twos, not how many numbers have a two. E.G. when it gets to 22 it increments twice, not once, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Given the number with the digits ABCDEF you can count the number of '2's in the ranges `[0,F], [0,E9], [0,D99], [0,C999], [0,B9999]` and `[0,A99999]` and add them.

Then for the range `[0, X9999...999]`, the top number `T = X9999...999` can be written as `(X+1) * 10<sup>nines</sup> -1`.

The number of '2's in that range is:

```
((X >= 2 ? 1/(X + 1)) : 0) + nines/10 ) * (T + 1);
```

That is: if `X >= 2`, the fraction of numbers that have a '2' at the position nines+1 is `1/(X+1)`, In total there are `(T+1)/(X+1)` '2's at that position. If `X < 2`, then no number on [0..T] has a '2' at that position.

For the other digit positions, is easy to see that at every digit position, `1/10` of the numbers have a '2', so there are `(T+1)/10` '2's at position 0, `(T+1)/10` '2's at position 1, etc. In total, `(T+1) * nines / 10`.

The complexity of this solution is O(logN).

Answer (score 0):

this is how I would go about coding my first draft (Python code)

```
def count2(n) :
    return [p for p in range(n+1) if '2' in str(p)]
```

and that will return you a list with the containing number.

In terms of performance it is not that bad, for n=10,000,000 an average iteration takes about 5.5 seconds