# Count the number of occurrences of 0's in integers from 1 to N

Tags: c, algorithm, math

How will you efficiently count number of occurrences of 0's in the decimal representation of integers from 1 to N?

```
e.g. The number of 0's from 1 to 105 is 16. How?

10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,101,102,103,104,105
```

Count the number of 0's & you will find it 16.

Obviously, a brute force approach won't be appreciated. You have to come up with an approach which doesn't depend on "How many numbers fall between 1 to N".
Can we just do by seeing some kind of pattern?

Cannot we extend the [logic compiled here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/22180) to work for this problem?

Comment: I thought you weren't suppose to leak those questions after an interview ;)

Comment: It's clearly proportional to `n^2`, so just do it brute force up to 10k or 100k to derive a constant and you're done.

Comment: @DeadMG, it is more likely in the order of `N log N` I'd say.

Comment: I love these sorts of questions. Chance of a practical application of the algorithm outside the classroom 0.00000000000000000000000000001%.

Comment: To make a distribution of digits in a range, it helps to count them. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford's_law

Comment: You could always `snprintf` each one and count the zeros... ;-)

Comment: In Python: `len(filter(lambda x: x=='0', ''.join([str(x) for x in xrange(1,n+1)])))`

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson: well those questions aren't suppose to be practical. They are supposed to check can you actually think. Nevertheless I don't like them either because I do not think they are pretty weak at doing that.

Comment: Never understood how a thoughtless question is meant to elicit a successful response. :)

Comment: Check out [Count the number of Ks between 0 and N?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20945790/2589776).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

My original answer was simple to understand but tricky to code. Here's something that is simpler to code. It's a straight-forward **non-recursive** solution that works by counting the number of ways zeros can appear in each position.

For example:

> x <= 1234. How many numbers are there of the following form?
>
> x = ??0?

There are 12 possibilities for the "hundreds or more" (1,2, ..., 12). Then there must be a zero. Then there are 10 possibilities for the last digit. This gives `12 * 10 = 120` numbers containing a 0 at the third digit.

The solution for the range (1 to 1234) is therefore:

- ?0??: 1 * 100 = 100
- ??0?: 12 * 10 = 120
- ???0: 123
- Total = 343

But an exception is if `n` contains a zero digit. Consider the following case:

> x <= 12034. How many numbers are there of the following form?
>
> x = ??0??

We have 12 ways to pick the "thousands or more". For 1, 2, ... 11 we can choose any two last digits (giving 11 * 100 possibilities). But if we start with 12 we can only choose a number between `00` and `34` for the last two digits. So we get `11 * 100 + 35` possibilities altogether.

---

Here's an implementation of this algorithm (written in Python, but in a way that should be easy to port to C):

```
def countZeros(n):
    result = 0
    i = 1

    while True:
        b, c = divmod(n, i)
        a, b = divmod(b, 10)

        if a == 0:
            return result

        if b == 0:
            result += (a - 1) * i + c + 1
        else:
            result += a * i

        i *= 10
```

Comment: For 1 to 999, your "special handling for the end condition" covers 90% of the range (100 to 999).  This is not a very good answer...

Comment: @Nemo, I think you misinterpreted that part. The rule is to split the number into ranges with equal numbers of digits, so [1,999] becomes ([1,9],[10,99],[100,999]), and then for each segment you do (high-low)*(length-1)/10, and add them together. The "special handling for the end condition" would be if instead of [1,999] we had something like [1,1234], where [1000,1234] doesn't fit in the pattern. It's only that last part that needs special handling.

Comment: @Kevin, I think understand perfectly...  How does this work for (1, 998)?  Or (1, 12345678)?

Comment: agree with Nemo, the special case diminishes the value of your solution, or else how you handle the special case becomes a critical, and complicating part of the solution. For 1..9998, the rule handles 1-999, and you're left to deal with 1000-9998 as a special case. Yes, though, he should have said 1 to 998, not 1 to 999.

Comment: @Nemo, I guess I'm confused by your first comment, then. In the case of [1,999], the special handling covers 0% of the range, not 90% as you suggested. Everything is covered in the [1,9],[10,99], and [100,999] ranges using the given rule.

Comment: @Kevin: Yes, I was thinking (1,666) or something, but I decided to go for broke and overreached.

Comment: @Nemo, that makes more sense. I agree that handwaving the special handling only works when the end point is near 10^x-1 for some integer x. For [1,998] we can obviously just go to [1,999] and subtract 0s (all none of them) as we count backwards, but for something like [1,666] we're going to need a better method.

Comment: @Mark: OK, so code it up so we can compare it to the other solutions :-)

Comment: @Nemo: There are 120. Here they are. Count 'em if you like: 100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,300,301,302,303,304,305,306,307,308,309,400,401,402,403,404,405,406,407,408,409,500,501,502,503,504,505,506,507,508,509,600,601,602,603,604,605,606,607,608,609,700,701,702,703,704,705,706,707,708,709,800,801,802,803,804,805,806,807,808,809,900,901,902,903,904,905,906,907,908,909,1000,1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,1100,1101,1102,1103,1104,1105,1106,1107,1108,1109,1200,1201,1202,1203,1204,1205,1206,1207,1208,1209

Comment: Your function `countZeros` does not work. Try it with n=9 (no zeros, returns 1) n=19 (1 zero, returns 2) etc etc. It is off by one with many values of n and more than 1 with large values.

Comment: If the following brute force method is correct (I believe it is): `len(filter(lambda x: x=='0', ''.join((str(x) for x in xrange(1,n+1)))))` then with n=1000000 your function returns 488890 and the one I just stated returns 488895. It is off by 2 with every n in [10001, 20001, 30001, etc]. It is off by 3 for every n in [500001, etc] off by 4 and 5 with larger magnitude numbers...

Comment: Isn't the problem definition inclusive of N? i.e., number of '0's in each string from '1' to '105' is 16 because you exclude the 0 before 1 and include the last 0 in 105, true? If mine includes the six '0's  '1000000' in 1 to n=1e6, that explains the difference, but I think you need to include those...

Comment: Now that you have provided code and debugged it, I am removing my downvote.  I still think the recursive formulation is simpler, but I agree this works.  P.S. @drewk's "expectations" are perhaps better called "giving the correct answer"

Comment: I'm sorry. I seem to have misunderstood.

Comment: From the output of the code, I think the algorithm is correct, but I do not understand why it won't double count for number that have 2 or more zeros? (IMO, inclusion-exclusion principle may be needed...), say you are counting ??0? and ???0  separately, why 1000 is not counted twice? (I know your algorithm is correct but I just can't figure it out)

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest adapting this algorithm from base 2 to base 10:

[Number of 1s in the two's complement binary representations of integers in a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942732/)

The resulting algorithm is O(log N).

The approach is to write a simple recursive function `count(n)` that counts the zeroes from 1 to `n`.

The key observation is that if N ends in 9, e.g.:

```
123456789
```

You can put the numbers from 0 to N into 10 equal-sized groups.  Group 0 is the numbers ending in 0.  Group 1 is the numbers ending in 1.  Group 2 is the numbers ending in 2. And so on, all the way through group 9 which is all the numbers ending in 9.

Each group except group 0 contributes `count(N/10)` zero digits to the total because none of them end in zero.  Group 0 contributes `count(N/10)` (which counts all digits but the last) plus `N/10` (which counts the zeroes from the final digits).

Since we are going from 1 to N instead of 0 to N, this logic breaks down for single-digit N, so we just handle that as a special case.

[update]

What the heck, let's generalize and define `count(n, d)` as how many times the digit `d` appears among the numbers from 1 to `n`.

```
/* Count how many d's occur in a single n */
unsigned
popcount(unsigned n, unsigned d) {
  int result = 0;
  while (n != 0) {
    result += ((n%10) == d);
    n /= 10;
  }
  return result;
}

/* Compute how many d's occur all numbers from 1 to n */
unsigned
count(unsigned n, unsigned d) {
  /* Special case single-digit n */
  if (n < 10) return (d > 0 && n >= d);

  /* If n does not end in 9, recurse until it does */
  if ((n % 10) != 9) return popcount(n, d) + count(n-1, d);

  return 10*count(n/10, d) + (n/10) + (d > 0);
}
```

The ugliness for the case `n < 10` again comes from the range being 1 to `n` instead of 0 to `n`...  For any single-digit `n` greater than or equal to `d`, the count is 1 except when `d` is zero.

Converting this solution to a **non-recursive** loop is (a) trivial, (b) unnecessary, and (c) left as an exercise for the reader.

[Update 2]

The final `(d > 0)` term also comes from the range being 1 to `n` instead of 0 to `n`. When `n` ends in 9, how many numbers between 1 and `n` inclusive have final digit `d`?  Well, when `d` is zero, the answer is `n/10`; when `d` is non-zero, it is one more than that, since it includes the value `d` itself.

For example, if `n` is 19 and `d` is 0, there is only one smaller number ending in 0 (i.e. 10). But if `n` is 19 and `d` is 2, there are two smaller numbers ending in 2 (i.e. 2 and 12).

Thanks to @Chan for pointing out this bug in the comments; I have fixed it in the code.

Comment: @Nemo, I posted a solution which I believe is something similar to what you suggested. I'm struggling with generalizing my solution. Can you please help me with it ? Thanks

Comment: @Nemo: Have you tested your solution? For `n = 20` with `d = 2`, there are 3 2's (2, 12, 20), but your solution yielded only 2.

Comment: @Chan: Indeed I had a bug whenever d is non-zero. Fixed; thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Let `Z(n) = #zero digits in numbers 0 <= k < n`. Obviously, `Z(0) = 0`.

If `n = 10*k + r, 0 <= r <= 9`, all `10*k` numbers `10*j + s, 0 <= j < k, 0 <= s <= 9` are in the range, each tenth last digit is 0, so that's `k` zeros, and each prefix `j` (all but the last digit) occurs ten times, but we mustn't count 0, so the number of zeros in the prefixes is `10*(Z(k)-1)`.

The number of zeros in the `r` numbers `10*k, ..., 10*k + (r-1)` is `r*number of zeros in k + (r > 0 ? 1 : 0)`.

So we have an `O(log n)` algorithm for computing `Z(n)`

```
unsigned long long Z(unsigned long long n)
{
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (n <= 10) {
        return 1;
    }
    unsigned long long k = n/10, r = n%10;
    unsigned long long zeros = k + 10*(Z(k)-1);
    if (r > 0) {
        zeros += r*zeroCount(k) + 1;
    }
    return zeros;
}

unsigned zeroCount(unsigned long long k)
{
    unsigned zeros = 0;
    while(k) {
        zeros += (k % 10) == 0;
        k /= 10;
    }
    return zeros;
}
```

To compute the number for an arbitrary range,

```
unsigned long long zeros_in_range(unsigned long long low, unsigned long long high)
{
    return Z(high+1) - Z(low); // beware of overflow if high is ULLONG_MAX
}
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Forgot to subtract the 0-prefixes, thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY No, 344 is correct,  `Prelude> length . filter (== '0') $ [0 .. 1233] >>= show` gives 344. `Z(n)` counts the zeros in `0, 1, ..., n-1`, so it must be at least 1 for all `n > 0`.

Answer (score 1):

I have a very simple way to do count 0's in between 1 to n.
I hope this will solve your issue and remove complexity

```
function countZero(n) {
  var count = 0;
  while (n > 0) {
    count += Math.floor(n / 10);
    n = n / 10;
  }
  console.log(count);
}

countZero(99);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class FindZero{

    public int findZero(int lastNumber){

        int count=1,k;
        if(lastNumber<10)
            return 0;
        else if(lastNumber==10)
            return 1;
        else{

            for(int i=11;i<=lastNumber;i++){
                k=i;
                while(k>0){

                    if(k%10==0)
                        count++;
                        k=k/10;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        FindZero obj = new FindZero();
        System.out.println(obj.findZero(1234));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# in single loop without using inbuilt functions

def func(n):
  lst=list(range(0,n+1)) #make list from 0 to n

  strng=str(lst) #convert list into string

  strng=strng[1:-1] #remove first and last square braces from string

  strng=strng.replace(",","") #remove commas

  strng=strng.replace(" ","") #remove spaces

  #now this is the complete string from 0 to n number
  count=0
  num=0
  for i in strng:
    if i==str(num):
      count += 1
  print(count)
func(10)

#Azizullah Ali
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The way I approached this problem:

numbers can be in the range 1 to N:

So, I broke this into ranges like this:

```
Rangle      : #Digits   :   #Zeros
1   -   9   :   1       :   0
10  -   99  :   2       :   9 (number of all the possible digits when zero is at units place=> _0 ie, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
100 -   199 :   3       :   20 => 10 (#digits when zero is at units place) + 10 (#digits when zero is at tens place)
200 -   276 :   3       :   18 => 8 (#digits when zero is at units place) + 10 (#digits when zero is at tens place)
300 -   308 :   3       :   10 => 1 (#digits when zero is at units place) + 9 (#digits when zero is at tens place)
1000-   1008:   4       :   19 => 1 + 9 + 9
```

Now for any given range 1 - N, I want to be able to break the number into these ranges and use the above logic to compute the number of zeros.

Test run:

for a given number N:

```
- compute number of digits: len
- if len = 1 : d1: return 0
- len = 2: d2_temp: count # of digits that can possibly occur when 0 is at unit's place 
            : for e.g. 76: so numbers can be between 10 - 76: (7 - 1) + 1 = 7
         : d2: sum(d2_temp, d1)
- len = 3: return d3 : sum(d3_temp, d2)
         : compute d3_temp: 
         : for e.g. n = 308 : get digit at 10^(len-1) : loopMax 3
         : d3_temp1: count number of zeros for this loop: 1 * 100 to (loopMax -1) * 100 : (loopMax-1) * 20
         : d3_temp2: for n count (#digits when zero is at units place) + (#digits when zero is at tens place)
         : d3_temp = d3_temp1 + d3_temp2
```

Lets try to generalise:

```
99 : sum( , )
    : d3_temp: 
    : loopMax: n = 99 : n/(10^1) : 9
    : d3_temp1: 8 : (9-1) * (10*(len-1)) : (loopMax - 1) * 10 * (len-1)
    : d3_temp2: 1 : for len, count #0s in range (loopMax * 10 * (len-1)) to n : count(90, 99)
    : d3_temp = 8 + 1
    : sum(9, 0)
    : 9
```

I'm having some trouble proceeding from here, but this would work.

Comment: @Nemo: I think this is similar to what you suggested. Can you please help me come up with generalising this to make a function out of it ?